# How to print correct length of appended list for how many days off when user inputs days?

Tags: python-3.x, list, pycharm

I am trying to set up code to create a program that reminds me what days i have off, what days i work, and at what times i work. it will also remind me to input schedule for next work week. for now though i will be doing some code to show what i will need to do until i have some more skill.

I have tried appending the list for sch_days_off and it returns an output of 1 when i try to print how many days i have off. i believe the strings i am using the wrong type of method to add to my list to try and count how many days i have off. I have also tried the count function, but it does not seem to be what i need, and if it it maybe i am not utilizing it correctly

```
days_of_week = ('Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 
'Friday', 'Saturday')

sch_days_off = []

def schedule_off():

    days_off = input("Please enter your days off:").split(' ')
    print(days_off)

    sch_days_off.append(days_off)

    print("This is how many days you have off: ")

def number_of_days_off():

    print("This is how many days you have off: %d" % len(sch_days_off))

schedule_off()
```

What i expected to print out would be the numbers of days i was off. i usually get two-three days off so i expect it to have an output of 2-3 not just one. Regardless it still gives me '1' as an output.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you append a list `days_off` to another list `sch_days_off` so `sch_days_off` becomes a two-dimenssional list. You print the number of list that contains `sch_days_off` (1).

Try this :

```
def schedule_off():

    days_off = input("Please enter your days off:").split(' ')
    print(days_off)

    for day in days_off:
      sch_days_off.append(day)

    print("This is how many days you have off: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you are appending the list `days_off` as an element to the list `sch_days_off`, that's why the `len()` always return 1. If you want to add all elements of `days_off` to `sch_days_off` you need to use `extend` instead of `append`.

```
def schedule_off():

    days_off = input("Please enter your days off:").split(' ')
    print(days_off)

    sch_days_off.extend(days_off)

    print("This is how many days you have off: ")
```